# Pycharm как отключить подсказки?

Tags: pycharm

Во время процесса написание кода, и Именно как в примере (на скриншоте), после ввода команды "print()" буквально через секунду как я перестал печатать, возникает вот такое окно (см.скрин), при этом если продолжить печатать во время появления окна, оно НЕ исчезает и собственно текст который печатаешь после его появление не вводиться.
[image: Данная подсказка возникает в разных случаях]

Как можно убрать эти подсказки ? 
Они вылетают и других случаях тоже, особенно когда этого меньше всего ожидаешь, и очень раздражают потому что приходиться тянуться к мышки и кликать куда-то в свободную область что бы она исчезла.

Сам пробовал искать конечно, в гугле тоже ничего не нашел похожего =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно отключить в **Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion**, опция **Auto-display parameter info**. Можно также увеличить задержку перед отображением окошка с подсказкой как вариант.

[image: Опция отключения parameter hints]